# SQL grouping user count by Mondays

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a Users table like so:

Users: id, created_at

How can I get the # of users created grouped by day? My goal is to see the number of users created this Monday versus previous Monday's.

Comment: Data type of `created_at`? Version of Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `created_at` is of type `timestamp`, the simplest and fastest way is a plain cast to `date`:

```
SELECT created_at::date AS day,  count(*) AS ct
FROM   users
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Since I am assuming that `id` cannot be `NULL`, `count(*)` is a tiny bit shorter and faster than `count(id)`, while doing the same.

If you just want to see days since **"last Monday"**:

```
SELECT created_at::date,  count(*) AS ct
FROM   users
WHERE  created_at >= (now()::date - (EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM now())::int + 6))
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

This is carefully drafted to use a [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) condition, so it can use a simple index on `created_at` if present.

Consider the manual for [`EXTRACT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS cnt, EXTRACT(DOW FROM created_at) AS dow
FROM Users
GROUP BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM created_at)
```

Comment: ERROR:  column "day" does not exist
LINE 3: GROUP BY DATEPART(DAY, created_at)

Comment: Thanks but the output doesn't say what day it is next to the count. Anyway to get the day? Ideally just Mondays?

Comment: @AnApprentice, clearly you can expand on the statement. I just showed you how to grab the day of the week so you can use the results to filter to just Mondays. Further, if you want the date itself simply look up the extract function, there are a ton of options.

Comment: Thanks but it's erroring: "ERROR:  column "users.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(id) AS cnt, EXTRACT(DOW FROM created_at) AS dow
                                                  ^
"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the days, use `to_char(<date>, 'Day')`.

So, one way to do what you want:

```
select date_trunc('day', created_at), count(*)
from users u
where to_char(created_at, 'Dy') = 'Mon'
group by date_trunc('day', created_at)
order by 1 desc;
```

Perhaps a more general way to look at it would be to summarize the results by day of the week, for this week and last week.  Something like:

```
select to_char(created_at, 'Day'),
       sum(case when created_at >= current_date - 6 then 1 else 0 end) as ThisWeek,
       sum(case when trunc(created_at) between current_date - 13 and current_date - 7 then 1 else 0 end) as LastWeek
from users u
group by to_char(created_at, 'Day')
```

Comment: ERROR:  function trunc(timestamp without time zone) does not exist
LINE 1: select trunc(created_at), count(*)
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Errors: "ERROR:  function trunc(timestamp without time zone) does not exist
LINE 1: select trunc(created_at), count(*)
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
"

Answer (score 0):

I am from a T-SQL background and I would do something like this

```
    CREATE TABLE #users
(id int,
 created_at datetime
 )

INSERT INTO #users
(id, created_at)
VALUES
(
  1, getdate()
  )

INSERT INTO #users
(id, created_at)
VALUES
(
  1, getdate()
  )


INSERT INTO #users
(id, created_at)
VALUES
(
  1, dateadd(DAY, 1,getdate())
  )

SELECT id, created_at, count(id) FROM #users
GROUP BY id, created_at

DROP TABLE #users
```

You will get better results if you only group by day part and not the entire datetime value.

Coming to second part - only comparing for Mondays; you can use something like

```
select datename(dw,getdate())
```

the above will give you the name of the weekday which you can compare against a string literal 'Monday'.